# What is the probability of drawing balls until you get 3 matching colors?

Tags: probability

A bag has $50$ balls - $37$ red, $10$ white, and $3$ blue. I draw balls without replacement until I pull out $3$ of the same color. What is the probability of each color that it is the first to be drawn 3 times?

My attempt: I know I have at least $3$ draws and at most $7$. I used hypergeometric distribution to figure the probability of the first three balls being the same color (red $39.6\%$, white $0.612\%$, blue $0.0051\%$). I figured the same with $4$, $5$, $6$, and $7$ balls but I do not know if I'm going in the right direction, and if so, how to figure the total probability of each color?

Answer (score 1):

You want the probability of, say, the third red being drawn before the third white, or third blue ; when there are 37 red, 10 white, 3 blue.

The probability that the third ball is red and the first two also red is $\left.{\binom{37}1\binom{36}{2}}\middle/{\binom{50}{1}\binom{49}{2}}\right.$

The probability that the fourth ball is red and two among the first three also red is   $\left.{\binom{37}{1}\binom32\binom{36}{2}\binom{13}{1}}\middle/{\binom{50}{1}\binom{49}{3}}\right.$

The probability that the fifth ball is red and two among the first four also red is   $\left.{\binom{37}{1}\binom42\binom{36}{2}\binom{13}{2}}\middle/{\binom{50}{1}\binom{49}{4}}\right.$

The probability that the sixth ball is red and two among the first five also red (yet not more than two of each other colour among the remaining 3) is: $\left.{\binom{37}{1}\binom52\binom{36}{2}\left[\binom 32\binom{10}2\binom 31+\binom31\binom{10}1\binom 32\right]}\middle/{\binom{50}{1}\binom{49}{5}}\right.$

The probability that the seventh ball is red and two among the first six also red (and only two of each of the other colour among the remaining 4) is: $\left.{\binom{37}{1}\binom62\binom{36}{2}\binom42\binom{10}2\binom 32}\middle/{\binom{50}{1}\binom{49}{6}}\right.$

$$\dfrac{37 \binom{36}2}{50}\left[\dfrac{1}{\binom{49}2}+\dfrac{\binom 31\binom{13}1}{\binom{49}3}+\dfrac{\binom42\binom{13}2}{\binom{49}{4}}+\dfrac{\binom 53\binom 32\left[\binom{10}2\binom 31+\binom{10}1\binom 32\right]}{\binom{49}5}+\dfrac{\binom64\binom 42\binom{10}2\binom32}{\binom{49}6}\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach:

Attack it like a Combinatorics problem, rather than a *probability of events* problem, but with a **twist**.

As discussed, you are only focusing on $7$ draws.  So, my approach will be

$$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}, \tag1 $$

where $~\displaystyle D = \binom{50}{7}.$  This means that I will be drawing exactly $(7)$ balls, regardless of whether a winner has already been declared.  It also means that when I am examining scenarios where there are two colors, each with $3$ or more draws (i.e. **the twist**), I have to delve more deeply into such scenarios.

In all cases, the denominator will be $~\displaystyle \binom{50}{7}~$, so the problem has been reduced to computing

$$N_{\text{red}}, N_{\text{white}}, N_{\text{blue}} ~: N_{\text{red}} + N_{\text{white}} + N_{\text{blue}} = \binom{50}{7}. \tag2 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~N_{\text{blue}}}$ 
Starting with the easiest color to compute, which will still illustrate the necessary *twist*.

Assuming that $3$ of the $7$ balls were blue, the following subcases have to be considered:

- Red $~= 2,~$ White $~= 2.$ 
  Enumeration is $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{3} \times \binom{37}{2} \times \binom{10}{2} = 29970.$ 
  All of these combinations count as a win for Blue, regardless of which of the seven positions, the three Blue balls were drawn in.
- [Red $~= 3,~$ White $~= 1]~$ and [Red $~= 1,~$ White $~= 3].$ 
  **Initial** enumeration is 
  $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{3} \times \left\{ ~\left[\binom{37}{3} \times \binom{10}{1}\right] 
  + \left[\binom{37}{1} \times \binom{10}{3}\right] ~\right\}
  = 82140.$ 
  By symmetry, exactly $(1/2)$ of these combinations will involve the 3rd Blue ball preceeding the 3rd Blue ball of the other color.
  Therefore, the enumeration in this case is **actually** 
  $\dfrac{1}{2} \times 82140 = 41070.$
- [Red $~= 4,~$ White $~= 0]~$ and [Red $~= 0,~$ White $~= 4].$ 
  **Initial** enumeration is 
  $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{3} \times \left\{ ~\left[\binom{37}{4} \times \binom{10}{0}\right] 
  + \left[\binom{37}{0} \times \binom{10}{4}\right] ~\right\}
  = 66255.$ 
  In order for one of the pertinent combinations to represent a win for Blue, the three Blue colors must all occur *somewhere* in the first five positions.
  Therefore, a *scaling factor* of 
  $\displaystyle \frac{\binom{5}{3}}{\binom{7}{3}} = \frac{10}{35} = \frac{2}{7}$ 
  must be applied to the initial enumeration. 
  This is what I was referring to as **the twist**. 
  Therefore, the enumeration in this case is **actually** 
  $\dfrac{2}{7} \times 66255 = 18930.$

Thus,

$$N_{\text{blue}} = 29970 + 41070 + 18930 = 89970.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~N_{\text{white}}}$ 
Method used will be very similar to the previous section.

The following subcases have to be considered:

- White $~= 5,6,~$ or $~7.$ 
  Enumeration is 
  $\displaystyle \left[\binom{10}{7}\right] 
  + \left[\binom{10}{6} \times \binom{40}{1}\right]
  + \left[\binom{10}{5} \times \binom{40}{2}\right]
  = 205080.$ 
  All of these combinations count as a win for White.
- White $~= 4.$ 
  Here, I will employ a shortcut.  All such combinations represent a win for White, except where Red or Blue $~= 3~$ **and** three of the first $5$ were not White.
  The **Initial** enumeration is 
  $\displaystyle \binom{10}{4} \times \binom{40}{3}
  = 2074800.$ 
  Similar to the analysis in the previous section, the number of combinations that must be deducted are $~\dfrac{2}{7} \times ~$ the number of [White $~= 4 ~: ~$ Red $~= ~3$] and [White $~= 4 ~: ~$ Blue $~= ~3$]combinations. 
  This works out to 
  $\displaystyle \frac{2}{7} \times \binom{10}{4} \times 
  \left[\binom{37}{3} + \binom{3}{3}\right] = 466260.$ 
  Therefore, for this subcase, the enumeration is 
  $2074800 - 466260 = 1608540.$
- White $~= 3.$ 
  Here, I will employ a moderately more complicated shortcut.  All such combinations represent a win for White, except, as discussed below, a certain fraction of the times where Red $~= 4~$ or Red $~= 3~$ or Blue $~= 3.$
  The **Initial** enumeration is 
  $\displaystyle \binom{10}{3} \times \binom{40}{4}
  = 10966800.$ 
  The first deduction is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{5}{7} \times \binom{10}{3} \times 
  \binom{37}{4} = 5661000.$ 
  The second deduction is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \times \binom{10}{3} \times
  \left\{ ~\left[\binom{37}{3} \times \binom{3}{1}\right] 
  + \left[\binom{37}{1} \times \binom{3}{3}\right] ~\right\} 
  = 1400820.$ 
  Therefore, for this subcase, the enumeration is 
  $10966800 - 5661000 - 1400820 = 3904980.$

Thus,

$$N_{\text{white}} = 205080 + 1608540 + 3904980 = 5718600.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~N_{\text{red}}}$ 
Analysis in this section will parallel the analysis in the previous section.

The following subcases have to be considered:

- Red $~= 5,6,~$ or $~7.$ 
  Enumeration is 
  $\displaystyle \left[\binom{37}{7}\right] 
  + \left[\binom{37}{6} \times \binom{13}{1}\right]
  + \left[\binom{37}{5} \times \binom{13}{2}\right]
  = 74517630.$ 
  All of these combinations count as a win for Red.
- Red $~= 4.$ 
  All such combinations represent a win for White, except where White or Blue $~= 3~$ **and** three of the first $5$ were not Red.
  The **Initial** enumeration is 
  $\displaystyle \binom{37}{4} \times \binom{13}{3}
  = 18888870.$ 
  Similar to the analysis in the previous section, the number of combinations that must be deducted are $~\dfrac{2}{7} \times ~$ the number of [Red $~= 4 ~: ~$ White $~= ~3$] and [Red $~= 4 ~: ~$ Blue $~= ~3$]combinations. 
  This works out to 
  $\displaystyle \frac{2}{7} \times \binom{37}{4} \times 
  \left[\binom{10}{3} + \binom{3}{3}\right] = 2283270.$ 
  Therefore, for this subcase, the enumeration is 
  $18888870 - 2283270 = 16605600.$
- Red $~= 3.$ 
  All such combinations represent a win for Red, except, as discussed below, a certain fraction of the times where White $~= 4~$ or White $~= 3~$ or Blue $~= 3.$
  The **Initial** enumeration is 
  $\displaystyle \binom{37}{3} \times \binom{13}{4}
  = 5555550.$ 
  The first deduction is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{5}{7} \times \binom{37}{3} \times 
  \binom{10}{4} = 1165500.$ 
  The second deduction is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} \times \binom{37}{3} \times
  \left\{ ~\left[\binom{10}{3} \times \binom{3}{1}\right] 
  + \left[\binom{10}{1} \times \binom{3}{3}\right] ~\right\} 
  = 1437450.$ 
  Therefore, for this subcase, the enumeration is 
  $5555550 - 1165500 - 1437450 = 2952600.$

Thus,

$$N_{\text{red}} = 74517630 + 16605600 + 2952600 = 94075830.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computations and Sanity Check}}$

$$\binom{50}{7} = 99884400.$$

The respective numerators are:

- $N_{\text{blue}} = 89970.$
- $N_{\text{white}} = 5718600.$
- $N_{\text{red}} = 94075830.$

$$89970 + 5718600 + 94075830 = 99884400.$$

Therefore, the respective probabilities of Red, White, or Blue winning are

$$\frac{94075830}{99884400}, ~\frac{5718600}{99884400}, ~\frac{89970}{99884400}.$$